# Firebase on iOS - Download GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

Now I’m writing the client for HackerNews (API: https://github.com/HackerNews/API). I want to use Firebase SDK but to work with it I need GoogleService-Info.plist. Where can I get it?

Answer (score 4):

To get your iOS app integrated with Firebase, [follow the instructions here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).  You will download the file from the Firebase console as part of setup.  If you need to download the file a second time, [follow the instructions here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592):

> To download a config file for an iOS app:
>
> - Sign in to Firebase and open your project.
> - Click the Settings icon and select Project settings.
> - In the Your apps card, select the bundle ID of the app you need a config file for from the list.
> - Click GoogleService-Info.plist.

Comment: I don't understand where I should download the file. I have to download the file from the console.firebase.google.com but I don't have access to HackerNews project. I need to get data from their database.